# Is it necessary for two objects to have same memory address in order to point to same thing in java

Tags: java

When you create two objects in java what happens when you set one equal to the other. What part of that object changes when we set it equal it to the other. Is it the memory address which is stored in the stack that gets changed or do they both start pointing to the same thing in heap memory without changing memory address stored in the stack?

I know when created initially they dont have the same memory address neither do they point to the same thing.

e.g
Test t1= new Test();

Test t2= new Test();

t2=t1;

This statement "t2=t1" is going to change actually what part of t2?

Comment: they `both start pointing to the same thing in heap memory`

Comment: So the answer is No...???
They can point to the same thing without changing their memory address in stack?
right?

Comment: value of `t2` changes too. actually your question doesn't make sense because both events happen

Comment: referring you to
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31755&seqNum=8 
where i got this explanation
What you're actually doing when you write this is assigning the address of the t1 object to the t2 object. Assume that t1's memory address was 0x33d444 and that t2's address was 0x99f775. After performing the above assignment, t2 now holds this address in stack memory: 0x99f775, which refers to the same object as t1. The t2 object on the heap still exists, but it cannot be accessed

Comment: *When you create two objects in java what happens when you assign one equal to the other* - that makes no sense- you dont assign object to another object.

Comment: There are simple 2 things - pointer (actually reference) to an object in memory, and that object in memory. You dont assignt objects one to another, you assign memory location to a pointer. Therefor you will end up with 2 pointers pointing the same memory region + garbage collectable phantom object.

Comment: "assign" meaning "set it equal"

Comment: No - asssign means assign.

Comment: already changed it to "set it equal"

Comment: @AhmedBajwa "assign" meaning "set the value of this left-hand-side variable to be the value of the right-hand-side variable and forget the old value of this left-hand-side variable"

Comment: both objects have their own memory addresses values stored in stack.
According to my knowledge the only way i can make t2 point to the same thing as t1 is i get memory address of t1 copied to memory address of t2 hence both pointing to same thing.

Comment: but i am confused by this article informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31755&seqNum=8 that says both can point to same thing without getting memory addresses altered.
if its not the memory addresses change that caused them point to same thing after t2=t1 then what was that?

Comment: You got O1 @ X and O2 @ Y. Now you say that a=X, b=Y and a=b. Why would I need to alter X or Y is a mistery to me.

Comment: because changing memory address value is what's going to make "a" point to something else

Answer (score 1):

```
Test t1= new Test();
```

This line creates a new `Test` object, and assigns it to `t1`

```
Test t2= new Test();
```

This line creates an additional `Test` object, and assigns it to `t2`

```
t2=t1;
```

This like assigns the object that was assigned to `t1`, also to `t2`. The original t2 object is now lost, and will be destroyed on the next garbage collector run.

```
This statement "t2=t1" is going to change actually what part of t2?
```

Think of t2 as a pointer. till that row it pointed to one object, now it points to another. the internal of these two objects are not changed by this line, only the pointer.

Comment: You mean pointer is independent of memory address value stored in stack?

Comment: more clearly my question is how many ways are there for an object to point to something different.
1: Changing its memory address value hence causing it to point to something else.
whats other?

Answer (score 0):

> When you create two objects in java what happens when you assign one
>   equal to the other

that makes no sense- you dont assign object to another object

There are simple 2 things - pointer (actually reference) to an object in memory, and that object in memory. You dont assignt objects one to another, you assign memory location to a pointer. Therefor you will end up with 2 pointers pointing the same memory region + garbage collectable phantom object

Comment: "assign" meaning "set it equal"

Comment: No, assign means assign. There is no "set it equal" operation. I think, that if you would use proper naming you would not have that question becuase "assign" is kind of self explainatory.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to forget about things like 'memory address' and 'stack'.  They are not concepts you need for Java programming.

The concepts you need are 'object' and 'reference'.

An expression like `new Test()` creates an *object* of class Test. The result of the expression is a *reference* to the object.

A variable is (excluding the primitive types like int, double, etc.) a slot that holds a reference, or `null` which is no reference at all.  A declaration like `Test t1` says that the variable named t1 can hold a reference to an object of class Test.

t1 is not an object, it is a reference.  The object is not called t1, the variable that (currently) refers to it is called t1.  (Though we'll be permitted to loosely say 'the object t1' because there's no other name for the object).

Assignment/initialization (we can regard them as equivalent here) stores the value of the expression on the right into the variable on the left.

Putting all that together,  `Test t1 = new Test()` declares a variable named t1 that can hold a reference to a Test object; a Test object is created; a reference to that Test object is stored into t1.  Note that t1 is not the object; t1 refers to the object.

Likewise of course `Test t2 = new Test()` declares a variable named T2 that gets a reference to a different Test object.

Now we execute `t2 = t1` -- the content of t2 is replaced by the content of t1. In other words, t2 and t1 have the same value, and that value happens to be a reference to the first Test object that was created.  Naturally, t2 does not now have a reference to the second Test object; in this example, nothing refers to that second object, so it is inaccessible and must remain so (because the only way to access it is through a reference we no longer have).

To underscore the point: assigning references does not change the objects themselves.

Not once did we need to mention memory addresses here.

Comment: Test t1=new Test();
//assume t1 has memory address  "ABC"
Test t2=new Test();
//assume t2 has memory address  "DEF"
t2=t1;
//t2 has now memory address changed to "DEF" because this is the only way t2 started poiting to same object as t1
Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by the word "has"? It's ambiguous since it could refer to the "address of" t2 or what t2 "contains". If you replace your use of "has" by "contains" then you are correct, with one caveat: we do not know, nor do we need to know, if a reference to an object is actually the memory address of that object.  It "refers" to it in a way the language understands; that is all that matters.